# Question about subject of participle clause

Tags: grammar

I've read a sentence from The New York Times:

> "Every new year brings curiosity and excitement. There is often a collective commitment from people to shed the toxic habits we developed the year before, while pushing to unlock the door of possibilities for the year to come."

What is the subject of the clause *while pushing to unlock the door of possibilities for the year to come*? It seems to be *people*, but it also feels like, grammatically, the subject is *collective commitment.*

Comment: I suppose it can be seen as a shortened form of ' ... There is often a collective commitment from us people to shed the toxic habits we developed the year before, while we are [at the same time] pushing to unlock the door of possibilities for the year to come.'

Comment: Well, the subject has to be human, and there are two human NPs in the sentence that it could be: _people_ and _we_. In fact, it appears that both are generic and refer to the same (unknown, indefinite) humans, so that will serve as the missing subject of _pushing,_  too (as well as of _shed_ and _unlock_, which are also missing their subjects).

Comment: *There is [a desire] **to shed** [something], while **pushing** [something else, at the same time]*. The "subject" of ***pushing*** is the same as the (not explicitly stated) subject of ***to shed***.

Comment: I'd say it's **people** that will be pushing to unlock the door of possibilities for the year to come."

Comment: Only a **dummy subject**: _**There** is a commitment to shed while pushing._